# MODULE_preprocess_block() get rendered region in drupal 8

Tags: blocks, hooks, 8, theming

So I am trying to port a Drupal 7 module to Drupal 8, and am struggling with how to translate a "NAME_preprocess_block" method. In the D7 code, it filters by the region a block is getting rendered

```
if ($vars['elements']['#block']->region == "my_region") {
   // Do stuff.
}
```

However, the "['#block']->region" object doesn't exist in drupal 8, and I can't seem to find an alternative. Is it still possible to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load the block(don't worry, it is already loaded so no performance impact).

```
$block = entity_load('block', $variables['elements']['#id']);
$region = $block->region;
```

Comment: Why when I use "$region = $block->region;" I get "protected property error". Any thought?

Comment: $block->getRegion()

Comment: Well, that function is no longer supported in drupal 8. use "\Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load($variables['elements']['#id']);" instead.

Comment: @Adrian I have no idea how, but there is a “Zero Width Non-Joiner.” character in between the i and d in your comment. Copy pasting your very helpful snippet led to the most sanity-questioning bug hunt of my life!

Answer (score 5):

So, getting everything working here is the code I got to work.

```
use Drupal\block\Entity\Block;
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_block().
 */
function harfang_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  $block = Block::load($variables['elements']['#id']);
  $region = $block->getRegion();

 // Add classes to all bocks in footer region.
  if($region == 'footer') {
 // Do something.
  }
}
```

added the use statement at the top and removed the non-joiners

Answer (score 0):

Here the correct version for Drupal 8.x:

```
$block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('block', $variables['elements']['#id']);
$region = $block->getRegion();
```

Comment: This is misleading. As of Drupal 8.2, passing the entity type to the load function like "Block::load('block', $id)" is redundant and throws errors. The correct version is the one mentioned in Adrian's comment.

Answer (score 0):

For drupal 8.2.x the above suggestions don't work anymore here is what worked for me

```
function MODULENAME_preprocess_block(&$variables ){
    $region = $variables['elements']['#configuration']['region'];
    if($region == "my_region"){
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Can also be implemented inside your `.theme` file with `THEMENAME_preprocess_block`

**NOTE** it seems that configuration region is available in a module preprocess function only when `context` module is enabled (!?) otherwise the region is only available in a theme preprocess function